# Выполнение строки как кода

Tags: delphi

Из поля ввода получаю от пользователя строку. Что-то наподобии
    string:= "a/b+c(d*e*f)";
Как некторой переменной например k, присвоить значение равное тому, что написано в строке?
Вот в яваскрипте есть функция eval(string) она выполняет код внутри себя, есть ли что-то типа такого в делфи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке такой возможности нет, но есть куча сторонних библиотек. [Вот](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=10) рассказано, как  написать такое чудо самому. А [здесь](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1130) уже готовенькое. Если чего то не хватает (например вычисления хитрой функции) - всегда можно добавить.